# How does YOLOv8 handle resolution discrepancies in images?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I have trained a YOLOv8 model with the COCO dataset (640x640) and implemented it into the Unity game engine using Sentis. This is intended to run on mobile devices, therefore utilizing the onboard camera to pass an image to the model and perform detection of the objects in view.

It runs well when I compress the provided image to the trained resolution, but it fails to detect objects properly when passing any other resolutions. It will create bounding boxes in random locations with random labels with no real order to the chaos it detects.

With some research, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268393/yolov8-how-does-it-handle-different-image-sizes) which specifies the constraints of the model, being that the images should be a resolution divisible by 32. While this wouldn't normally be an issue to utilize a different camera configuration in Unity that supports a resolution that conforms to this, doing so results in the same issues.

Strangely enough, running the same model in my Jupyter runtime with any image resolution (not conforming to the divisible-by-32 rule) results in a perfectly segmented image with no real issues.

My question is: Why? Shouldn't I expect the same performance between the model running on Jupyter and in Unity considering they are the same? Why would the Unity version only work with images fitting the 640x640 resolution it was trained on, but any resolution works when running it outside of Unity?